# How to use generate Id for different values in calculated columns?

Tags: sql-server

I have a big query (which is already ordered as per my needs), one of the columns is calculated (varchar combination of other columns in the query). I need an incremental integer to identify this calculated column (duplicates should have the same id).
I can´t use rank because the order in which I need the incremental number uses another criteria than the one used to generate the calculated column.

This is what I need:

```
OrderByColumn              CalculatedColumn          GeneratedId
    1                        ggg                       1
    1                        aaa                       2
    1                        ggg                       1
    1                        fff                       3
    2                        vvv                       4
    2                        ddd                       5
    3                        ggg                       1
    4                        rrr                       6
    5                        aaa                       2
    5                        ooo                       7
    5                        kkk                       8
    8                        vvv                       4
    9                        aaa                       2
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY XXX ORDER BY YYY)
```

assuming you are using SQL2005 or better

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

-- though like you said this doesn't solve your dupes with same ID thing - ahhh! Give me a moment - should be able to do this pretty easy

Edit:

Here you go -

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f014/2

```
-- Select stuff:
select vals.val as genid, ord.* from ord
-- Join back to a distinct list of CalculatedColumn with a row_number() to id them
inner join
(select calculatedcolumn, row_number() over (order by calculatedcolumn) as val  from ord group by calculatedcolumn) as vals on vals.calculatedcolumn = ord.calculatedcolumn
order by ord.orderbycolumn
```

Of course this is using the calculated column in the subquery - so you will need to re-calculate unless you store the value in a temp table or table variable

Comment: That's what I'd do. Problem is, it's ugly as sin, and probably runs like a cow. Maybe make it a CTE: start with the "base" query generating the data, then join that with itself to get the proper order and ranking? Can't really do this without having the "base" code, however.

Comment: Yeah she's real ugly - and she moves like a slug in poo, but she gets the job done.. that's why I love her

Comment: I see - hang on, actually might be a while got some laundry to do :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but there's a little problem with it, I need the GenId to start at 1 respecting the current order of the results. In your solution the first GenId is '4', I need it to be '1'. And the next time it finds a different calculated column make GenId = '2'. You know what I mean?

Comment: man, forget about the laundry, I´ll give you points if you fix it!!